# Use same branch more than once

Tags: git, git-branch

I am new to git, and I am assuming that if I can use only one branch for all project. After I commit my code into a branch -- `subBranch`, and merge it into the `master`. Then I did some other change. May I commit them into the `subBranch` again and merge into the `master`, or I have to make a new branch?

Comment: You don't have to create a new branch each time.

Comment: [Tag:GitHub] is about the website, this is more about git.

Answer (score 2):

You need read some materials about [git branch model, or git workflow. The following two links will be a good start.

[git wokflow](https://sandofsky.com/blog/git-workflow.html)

[git branch model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

You need not creating new branch for your case as you described in your question, but if you have needs to work on multiple new features, or interrupted by certain hot fix request, a new branch will be a help.

Answer (score 1):

It is common to use reuse the same branch in this way.

For example, suppose you have a 'dev' branch and a 'maintenance' branch. You may do lots of commits on the 'dev' branch, and periodically merge 'dev' into 'maintenance'. After merging, you can do more commits on 'dev'.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create branch every time you want push your change into the master branch.. use the branch for divide the tasks for your project.. for this issue.. you can use the same branch..